# How to backup an SQL Server 2008 Express database that exists as an .mdf file?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, database-backups

I have been trying various backup scripts to back up my database but i have been encountering various error. I Even tried taking backup using SMO in C# as well but it wont let me restore saying that process is using this file.

Another option i tried was simple `BACKUP DATABASE` statement but it gives me following error

> Incorrect Syntax Near 'F:\DIR\DIR\APP_DATA***.mdf'

Need some help using this database backup.

Thanks.

Comment: do you have sql express installed ? Then you can attach it and take backup

Comment: If you have a syntax error, you should probably include your syntax.

Comment: Yes i have it installed. and the syntax is
 BACKUP DATABASE N'F:\SILVER CLOUD\ONLINE COLLEGE ADMINISTRATION\APP_DATA\COLLEGE.MDF' TO DISK = 'D:\Test.bak'

Comment: You cannot back up a "stand-alone" `.mdf` file - either just copy the file elsewhere, or then you need to **attach** the `.mdf` to a SQL Server (Express) instance under a logical database name, and **then** you can do a `BACKUP DATABASE` on it

Comment: first attach it with your sql server, and take back doing right click on the database-> Tasks->Back up ...

Comment: I tried to attach it but its not showing up.

Comment: Why is there *** in filename in the error message?

Comment: That is just a sample.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a post few years back on how to backup and restore DB using SMO along with a solution [here](http://midnightprogrammer.net/csharp/backuprestore-sql-database-using-c/).

Moreover, you cannot access .MDF file while the SQL server service is running in the background. Even if you try to copy the file the process will not allow that too.

Comment: That, too, only works on a database that's attached to a SQL Server instance, correct? I don't see any functionality to just plain back up a standalone `.mdf` file as the original poster asked for....

Comment: Correct...It won't. You cannot restore MDF file programatically and cannot access it as SQL service is using it in the background. You can't even copy the MDF file while the service is running.

Comment: Yes exactly that is the problem i am facing.I am not even able to copy it. I even tried tried to detach it but it wont let me detach or even attach it.

Comment: You need to stop the service. Go to RUN by pressing WIN+R and then type services.msc and then locate SQL Server service. Right click and select stop to stop the service. Once the service is stopped you  will be able to copy it.

Comment: Thanks but the thing is I want to provide a backup service on a button click event so i need to do this all in coding.

Comment: I doubt you can do it with the service running in the background. You need to figure out a way to stop a service programatically and then try to copy the file. Why don't you just take a backup of the DB instead of using working with MDF file? I believe that would be easy!!